# how to run Simple node js api?

Tags: node.js, express

#server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
app.get('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
   fs.readFile( __dirname  + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      console.log( data );
      res.end( data );
   });
})
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

this is my server.js code from which I am calling the user.json file for the data

#user.json

```
{
   "user1" : {
      "name" : "mahesh",
      "password" : "password1",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 1
   },
   "user2" : {
      "name" : "suresh",
      "password" : "password2",
      "profession" : "librarian",
      "id": 2
   },
   "user3" : {
      "name" : "ramesh",
      "password" : "password3",
      "profession" : "clerk",
      "id": 3
   }
}
```

This is my file in which my list of user are there

But when I run the app I didn't get any data

Comment: You don't need to use `fs.readFile`. You can simply require it and it will be read properly as a JSON and an object will be created. Then you can simply send that object.

Answer (score 3):

First of all use `path` when you are trying to get a file path.

```
   path.resolve(__dirname, "users.json");
```

Second of all add error handling, because you may receive an error and that is why you see no data.

```
   fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "users.json"), 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
          res.status(500);
          res.end(err.message);

          console.error(err);
          return;
      }
      console.log( data );
      res.end( data );
   });
```

Comment: please fix the file name. it is "users.json" and not "users.jso"

Comment: Thanks! I have fixed the name

Answer (score 0):

This should make it work as required,

- Added ES6 Syntax
- Added Error Handling

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");

app.get('/listUsers', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('user.json', (err,data) => {
        if(err) res.status(500).send(err.message)
        else {
            let displayData = JSON.parse(data);
            //console.log(displayData)
            res.status(200).send(displayData);
        }
    });
})

app.listen(8081,() => console.log("Example app listening at port 8081"))
```

Without using `fs`

```js
const user = require('./user.json')

app.get('/listUsers', (req, res) => {
        res.send(user);
})
```

Comment: Using requires is not the best solution, because we require it once and then it lives in the memory so any changes to the file won't make it to the running program.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
fs.readFile( __dirname  + "/user.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      console.log( data );
      res.end( data );
   });
```

1. You probably just misstyped file name - you have users.json instead of user.json
2. Add / before file name
3. Add error handling.

Comment: try-catch block won't catch async errors.

Comment: The truth is that the example you are showing is not use `async/await` and the only way to handle the error in this example will be checking `err` parameter of the callback.

Comment: Edited my answer. Anything else?